# Why Grid puts the lines under each other (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to append Main Menu into first grid's row and put canvas into second row.
At runtime I see, that second row rendering under first row. Why? What's wrong?

I can set margin from top, but it's bad and not need at this project.

Screenshot:
[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tDXp.png)

```
<Window x:Class="OlodimStories.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OlodimStories"
        Title="Olodim Stories" 
        WindowState="Maximized"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ManipulationStarting="Window_ManipulationStarting"
        ManipulationDelta="Window_ManipulationDelta"
        ManipulationInertiaStarting="Window_InertiaStarting" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>

        <MatrixTransform x:Key="InitialMatrixTransform">
            <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                <Matrix OffsetX="200" OffsetY="200"/>
            </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
        </MatrixTransform>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="rootCanvas" Background="Green" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Menu Name="mainMenu" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent" 
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <MenuItem Header="Меню" FontSize="16">
                <MenuItem Header="Открыть" FontSize="16"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Сохранить" FontSize="16" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Name="addImageItem" FontSize="16" Header="Добавить изображение..." Click="AddImageItem_Click"/>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Name="exitApp" Header="Выход" FontSize="16"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Did you forget `<Grid.RowDefinitions>`?

Comment: @KlausGütter, yes! One minute ago I think about it - before your answer:)) You can add answer and I will mark it tomorrow =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Grid.RowDefinitions>` is missing:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```